# How do I detect if a browser does not support changing html audio volume?

Tags: javascript, html, ios, mobile-safari

So I recently discovered that iOS Safari does not allow volume to be controlled through javascript on audio elements. Fine. But how do I detect it to not show a control for it in my custom player?

From their [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/Using_HTML5_Audio_Video/Device-SpecificConsiderations/Device-SpecificConsiderations.html):

`On iOS devices, the audio level is always under the user’s physical control. The volume property is not settable in JavaScript. Reading the volume property always returns 1.`

So I thought I'd extend some trust to Apple's documentation (which is always a mistake), and believe them when they say `Reading the volume property always returns 1`. So I created this function that simply changes the volume of an audio element and then checks if it changed, and changes it back if not.

Turns out the documentation was wrong, and actually, at least in synchronous code, it momentarily stays at 0.9 and so this function always returns true.

```js
function isVolumeChangeable(audioElement) {
  const lastSetting = audioElement.volume
  audioElement.volume = 0.9
  const changed = audioElement.volume == 0.9 // Supposed to equal one in iOS
  audioElement.volume = lastSetting // Change it back
  return changed
}
```

Now I can be really dirty and put some kind of timeout in there, but there *has* to be a better way.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use navigator.userAgent (docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/userAgent) and do some regex to detect iOS / Safari?

Comment: Very bad idea in general. Feature detection is the way to go for things like these. And in any case, I suppose OP is looking for a solution to the issue, not how to detect whether the browser is iOS or not.

Comment: I totally agree @MarcoBonelli, therefor I think this approach is the way to go. We're talking about a paradigm Apple's not going to let go, after all. Or in other words, iOS === no volume control in players. Added benefit here is that it's (sorta) future proof. Regardless of Apple's implementation, and future iOS releases, simply detecting OS gives you all you need to know about the visibility of the volume controls.

Comment: You "totally agree" that it is a very bad idea and therefore it "is the way to go"? What...? You just contradicted yourself. Besides, detecting stuff using userAgent is definitely NOT future proof, behavior could change in the future. Detecting the OS through userAgent is also flawed, you shouldn't do it unless it's a toy app.

Comment: For the record: settimeout for 0ms and checking again returned 1 on the volume so my function works with that slight modification. Dirty, yes, but I think it's the most reliable way.